# webkitAudioContext undefined in safari browser

Tags: google-chrome, safari, html5-audio, webkitaudiocontext

I trying in console (chrome) `webkitAudioContext` and it's defined (function with native code).

```
webkitAudioContext
function AudioContext() { [native code] }
```

In safari (5.1.6) it's returns 'message: "`Can't find variable: AudioContext`"'.

```
AudioContext
Error
line: 2
message: "Can't find variable: AudioContext"
sourceId: 4569334656
__proto__: Error



webkitAudioContext
Error
line: 2
message: "Can't find variable: webkitAudioContext"
sourceId: 4647161912
__proto__: Error
```

Can I use `webkitAudioContext` in safari?

Thanks!

### EDIT:

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
Error
line: 2
message: "Can't find variable: webkitAudioContext"
sourceId: 4603762264
__proto__: Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot: http://caniuse.com/audio-api

It's only supported in Safari 6.0+.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can use it. Try invoking it with a `new` keyword and include the parenthesis after it.

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
```